# How to split a Pounds decimal value correctly in C++ to Pounds and Ounces?

Tags: c++, function, type-conversion

Following are the two functions I have written to convert Kg to Pounds and vice versa. I am calling these two from my `main()` using a `switch` case.

```
void poundToKg(double pounds, double ounces) {
    pounds = pounds + (ounces / 16);
    cout << "Pound to KG : " << pounds * 0.453592 << " Kgs" << endl;
}

void kgToPound(double kilograms, double grams) {
    kilograms = kilograms + (grams / 1000);
    cout << "KG to Pound : " << kilograms * 2.20462 << " Pounds" << endl;
}
```

For example, if I want to do a KG to Pounds conversion, I enter:

> Kg : 300
> Grams : 100
> My Output : 661.606 Pounds

I want to print the output separately in kilograms and grams OR pounds and ounces.
I wanted to print something like `x Pounds and y Ounces` with 661.606 or any example.

I was thinking of separating like `661 Pounds and 0.606 Ounces`. Is that the correct approach/solution?

Note: The input will be two values, input 1 - Weight in Kg or Pounds
input 2 - Grams or Ounces.

Comment: You're almost there, 0.606 is still in pounds, to get ounces multiply that by 16.

Comment: There is a big difference between 0.606 ounces and 606 ounces.

Comment: You may want to check `std::modf`

Answer (score 0):

For the pounds, you can cast your double to an int :

```
std::cout << (int)x;
```

For the ounces, you can do something like :

```
std::cout << x - (int)x;
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering 1 lbs = 16 oz, you need to get the fraction part and multiply by 16:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

void kg_to_lbs(double const kg) {
  double total_lbs = 2.205 * kg;
  double lbs;
  double oz = std::modf(total_lbs, &lbs) * 16;

  std::printf("%.0f lbs and %.2f oz\n", lbs, oz);
}

int main() { 
  kg_to_lbs(300.1); 
}
```

This prints "661 lbs and 11.53 oz".

Comment: The input is going to be two vlaues. One in kg and other in grams. I need to convert them in lb and oz

Comment: For Example, if I have 200 kg and 10 grams
After conversion to Pounds, it will be 440.946 Lb
I need to present this  ` 440.946 Lb ` value in such a way that it shows like  x Lb and y oz

Comment: @Zoori that should be easy to handle. Just call it like `kg_to_lbs(kg + gr / 1000.0);`. Or take two params and do the conversion inside the function.